# How to get the information about when wifi connection was established?

Tags: android

I need to get some information about my wifi connection, MAC address, time of initial connection, connection duration. I don't want to use broadcast receivers because those don't work anymore with android O.
Is there some other way to get this information?
I found that WifiConfiguration has a field `lastConnected` and `lastDisconnected`, however there're no documentation on those fields, and the vaules that I get are 0.

Is it possible to get this information some other way, maybe using proc/net?

Comment: *"broadcast receivers because those don't work anymore with android O?"* Only if you declare them in the manifest. If you register them in your code, they work.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I need them to work all the time, even if the app is killed.

Answer (score 0):

Use [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics) for that. You can schedule work by conditions including WiFi state.

Comment: Can it be scheduled to work, whenever the user connects or disconnects from WIFI, regardless of the app running state?